# Registering different implementations

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

In the business layer, I have 3 service interface
`IUserService` `IRoleService` and `IGroupService`

and one validator interface IValidator
IValidator has 3 implementations - `UserValidator`,`RoleValidator`, `GroupValidator`.

```
IUserService is implemented by UserService(IValidator userValidator)
IRoleService is implemented by RoleService(IValidator userValidator)
IGroupServiceis implemented by GroupService(IValidator userValidator)
```

All the three services take IValidator as the constructor param.

In the web layer, I have 3 controllers `UserController` taking in `IUserService` as the constructor param, `RoleController` taking in `IRoleService` as the constructor param, 
and Group Controller taking in `IGroupServiceas` the constructor param

**My question:**
How do i force roleService to get `RoleValidator` object and `GroupService` to get `GroupValidator` object.

I am using castle windsor 3.1

```
          windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<IValidator>()
         .ImplementedBy<UserValidator>()
         .Named("userValidator")
          .LifestyleTransient());

          windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<IValidator>()
         .ImplementedBy<RoleValidator>()
         .Named("roleValidator")
          .LifestyleTransient());

          windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<IValidator>()
         .ImplementedBy<GroupValidator>()
         .Named("groupValidator")
          .LifestyleTransient());
```

I used `IsFallback()` while registering userValidator but all the 3 services get roleValidator object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windsor lets you do this with [Service Overrides](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx#Supplying_the_component_for_a_dependency_to_use_Service_override_9).

**UPDATE**

Given the following setup:

```
public interface IMyService
{
}

public class Concrete1 : IMyService
{
}

public class Concrete2 : IMyService
{
}

public class ClassA
{
    private IMyService service;

    public ClassA(IMyService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    private IMyService service;

    public ClassB(IMyService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Here's how you could use the `DependsOn` to pick which `IMyService` implementation is used by the "service" parameter of `ClassA` and `ClassB` constructors:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(
    Component.For<IMyService>().ImplementedBy<Concrete1>().Named("C1"),
    Component.For<IMyService>().ImplementedBy<Concrete2>().Named("C2"),
    Component.For<ClassA>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("service", "C1")),
    Component.For<ClassB>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("service", "C2"))
    );
```

Comment: Service Overrides is not an option in Windsor 3.1

Comment: What makes you say that? Service Overrides were added in 3.0.

Comment: I do not get serviceoverride option when i type "Component.For<IRoleService>()."

Comment: Try using the "DependsOn" option (it looks like ServiceOverrides have been replaced with the DependsOn functionality).

Comment: Could you be more specific about "doesn't work"?  I just tried it on some old code that used to use ServiceOverride and it worked fine.

Comment: I might be doing something incorrect.Could you please provide an example. **My Code**
          `windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<IValidator>()
         .ImplementedBy<GroupValidator>()
         .Named("groupValidator")
          .LifestyleTransient());`  **Service registration**              `windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<IGroupService>()
         .ImplementedBy<GroupService>()
         .DependsOn(new GroupValidator()
          .LifestyleTransient());`

Comment: I updated my original response with the some code that uses DependsOn to pick which implementation of an interface is used.